# Global GET Management in Flask

Tags: python, flask, get

Is there any way of a 'global GET management' in Flask?

For example:
I want to show an error message, via popover, on any page of my flask application. If the user clicks on the 'close' button, the application will make a reload of the page with a new get parameter 'message_read=1'.
I want to catch this GET parameter. I am quite sure there is a better way then writing a check in every single app.route (which are a lot). Could you give me a hint please.

Thank you.

Comment: check the answers and accept or comment

Answer (score 0):

Add a before request function and handle it there. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.before_request

```
@app.before_request
def do_stuff():
    arg = request.args.get('message_read')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `decrators` .  Read about python decorators [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)

Here is a demonstration of custom decorator with flask.The code below shows a decorator definition and usage for your use case

**Code**

```
from flask import Flask,request
from functools import wraps


def popup_message(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def f_(*args,**argv):
         message_read = request.args.get('message_read', None)
         if message_read is not None:
             return  message_read
         else:
             return f(*args,**argv)
    return f_




app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/earth')
@popup_message
def hello_earth():
    return 'Hello,earth'

@app.route('/world')
@popup_message
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!' 

app.run()
```

**Usage**

Run the app as

```
python  main.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and try making request to /earth and  /world with and without `message_read`